# How to select a SiteMapNode from sitemap using code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, asprepeater, sitemapnode

I am busy working building my own custom navigation page in ASP.Net. I'm busy trying to fill an `<asp:Repeater>`'s data with a specific `SiteMapNode` from my `web.sitemap` file.

Here is my `web.sitemap`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode roles="*">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Secure/Home" title="Home">
            <!-- Home SiteMapNodes -->
        </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode url="~/Secure/Maintenance title="maintenance">
            <!-- Maintenance SiteMapNodes -->
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

In my Home navigation page I have the following repeater set up:

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMenu" DataSourceID="smdsMain" OnItemDataBound="rptMenu_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a runat="server" href='<%# Eval("url") %>'>
                    <%# Eval("title") %>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="smdsMain" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" SiteMapProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" />
```

I'm attempting to fill the `<asp:Repeater>` in the code behind using the `OnItemDataBound` method like this:

```
protected void rptMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode homeNode = ???;
    ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptMenu")).DataSource = homeNode;
    ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptMenu")).DataBind();
}
```

My only question is how to I set the `homeNode` `SiteMapNode` to the SiteMapNode with the `title` `home`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some chopping and changing and a bit of research I came to a solution using the `SiteMap.Provider.FindMapNodeFromKey(key)` method. Where `key` is the `url` of the `web.sitemap` node.

I also realized that I shouldn't be using the `OnItemDataBound` method to set my `rptMenu`'s `DataSource`. So I did in the the `Page_Load` method.

As a result, here is my working `Page_Load` code:

```
var homeNode = SiteMap.Provider.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("~/Secure/Maintenance");
rptMenu.DataSource = homeNode.ChildNodes;
rptMenu.DataBind();
```